# Removing JTable row when sorter is applied causes IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, swing, filter, jtable, tablerowsorter

I have a JTable with rows of custom objects, one column of which is a time component that counts down. When the countdown reaches 0 the row is to remove itself automatically.

I also have a filter option via textbox that the user can type into to filter the rows by their data.

Without the sorter applied to the JTable, everything works correctly (rows removing themselves when the time counts to 0) besides filtering. Applying the sorter gives me an "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index"

My custom table model looks like this

```
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

    CustomObject myObject = customObjects.get(rowIndex);
    if (columnIndex == MyFirstColumn) {
        return myObject.getData1();
    } else if (columnIndex == MySecondColumn) {
        return myObject.getData2();
    } else if (columnIndex == TimeRemainingColumn) {
        if (myObject.getDate() - System.currentTimeMillis() <= 0) {

            //If I comment this out I can filter but not remove rows
            removeRow(myObject); 

            return 0;
        }
        else{
            fireTableDataChanged();
            return myObject.getDate() - System.currentTimeMillis();
        }  
    }

    return DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date(myObject.getDate()));
}


public void removeRow(CustomObject object) {
    int row = customObjects.indexOf(object);
    customObjects.remove(object);
    fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
}
```

This throws this exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.convertRowIndexToModel(DefaultRowSorter.java:514)
at javax.swing.JTable.convertRowIndexToModel(JTable.java:2645)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5718)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:684)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:581)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
....
```

Going to DefaultRowSorter.java it is hitting this exception

```
public int convertRowIndexToModel(int index) {
    if (viewToModel == null) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= getModelWrapper().getRowCount()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index");
        }
        return index;
    }
    return viewToModel[index].modelIndex;
}
```

Up Another level, why removing works without a sorter (sorter == null)

```
public int convertRowIndexToModel(int viewRowIndex) {
    RowSorter sorter = getRowSorter();
    if (sorter != null) {
        return sorter.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRowIndex);
    }
    return viewRowIndex;
}
```

Debugging a bit firstRow and endRow are both 0 at that point (they should be?) But it seems to be attempting to sort/filter an empty list

Heres my table code

```
    myModel = new CustomObjectDataModel();

    myTable.setModel(myModel);
    mySorter = new TableRowSorter(myModel);

    myTable.setRowSorter(mySorter);
    myTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

I've searched around and found dead links to suggesting this is a bug in Java but can't confirm.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) *"found dead links to suggesting this is a bug"*  If they were dead links, how could they communicate that to you?  Did you conduct a séance? ;)

Comment: I'll see if I can post a working example, as far as dead links go. Searching around the internet for my problem has lead me to websites that run into a similar problem and refer to dead Java pages.

Comment: I don't think your strategy of auto-removing is a good one, if even valid. I would use a background job that would remove obsolete rows every second or so (using a Swing Timer). This way, you'll never have a situation where the number of rows returned by `getRowCount()` will be in contradiction with the indices you can use to call `getValueAt()`.

Comment: I thought about that strategy as well. The reason I attempted this was because I am also adding new rows to the table from another thread at potentially the same time as rows that need to be removed. If I am looping over my data model I run into concurrentModification issues.

Comment: Thet means that you're modifying the model from a background thread, which is forbidden by Swing. You should only access Swing components and their model from the event dispatch thread. The background thread should only be there to do background tasks or sleep until some row must be removed or added, and then do the modification of the model in the EDT, using a Swing Timer or by calling `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

Comment: remove all your own event, f.e. posted removeRow(myObject); inside getValueAt (and another) caused endless recrusion, then post an SSCCE, otherwise everything here are shots to the dark

Comment: I can verify some of the previous comment, of you try and modify the TableModel outside the EDT, you will get this error, took me e weeks to track this one down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented this using Swing Timers instead as suggested and fixed the issue, but the problem here was modifying the table model outside of the EDT.